# CSS Header Bug - Hover Changes Positions

Tags: jquery, html, css

EDITED to include header HTML/CSS

I'm working on my header at http://tremor.yt/Site/Creators.html .

There is a bug where, when a user hovers over the links in the header from right to left, the positions of the links get all jumbled. Not sure what is going on.

I would love to make a JSFiddle, but I have tried and it doesnt seemt o be working out, as it is tightly tied in with my page, which you can see here: http://tremor.yt/Site/Creators.html.

Header HTML:

```
<!-- HEADER -->



    <header>
        <div class="Header">
            <div class="Header_Container">
                <a href="www.xenova.tv"><div class="Logo"></div></a>

<!-- NAVIGATION -->

                <div class="middle-nav">
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="Home.html"><div class="HOME" class="nav_hover">HOME</div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Creators.html"><div class="CREATORS  nav_hover">CREATORS</div></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu cnav">
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">WHY XENOVA</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">SPOTLIGHT</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">FAQ</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                <span style="font-size:85%;">JOIN</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="VERTICALS  nav_hover">VERTICALS</div></a>

                <ul class="sub-menu vnav">
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">ABOUT</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">SPOTLIGHT</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">FAQ</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                <span style="font-size:85%;">INQUIRE</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="XENOVA_  nav_hover">XENOVA+</div></a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu Xnav">
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">PREMIUMS</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">FAQ</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">JOIN</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="ABOUT  nav_hover">ABOUT</div></a>

            <ul class="sub-menu anav">
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">WHAT WE DO</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">HISTORY</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                 <span style="font-size:85%;">FUTURE</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu-style"><a href="#" class="sub-menu click">
                <span style="font-size:85%;">CONTACT</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="CONTACT nav_hover">CONTACT</div></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://wellspringinfotech.com/kyle/form/login.php"><div class="LOG_IN nav_hover">LOG IN</div></a>
    </li></ul></div> 

<!-- END NAVIGATION -->

<!-- SOCIAL LINKS -->

        <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><div class="Icon_BG1"></div></a>
        <a href="http://www.skype.com"><div class="Icon_BG_2"></div></a>

<!-- END SOCIAL LINKS -->

        </div> <!-- Header Container -->
    </div> <!-- Header -->
    </header>

<!-- END HEADER -->
```

Header CSS:

```
/* HEADER CSS */

.Header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 94;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.6s;
    transition: height 0.6s;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s;
}
.Header.small {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 94;
  background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.6s;
    transition: height 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}
.Header_Container {
  width:1000px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.Sub_menus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1912px;
  height: 2292px;
  z-index: 93;
}
    .nav_hover:hover {
    color: #c1c1c1;
    -webkit-transition: color .25s;
    }
.Icon_BG_2 {
  background: url("images/IconBG2.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 960px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 82;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Icon_BG_2.small {
  background: url("images/IconBG2.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 960px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 82;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Icon_BG_2.small:hover {
  background: url("images/IconBGHover2.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 960px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 82;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
}
.Icon_BG_2:hover {
  background: url("images/IconBGHover2.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:960x;
  top: 26px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 82;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
}
.Icon_BG1 {
  background: url("images/IconBG.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 905px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 80;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Icon_BG1.small {
  background: url("images/IconBG.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 905px;
  top: 10px;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 80;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Icon_BG1.small:hover {
  background: url("images/IconBGHover.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 905px;
  top: 10px;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 80;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;

}
.Icon_BG1:hover {
  background: url("images/IconBGHover.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:905px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 80;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
}
.LOG_IN {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:660px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
  }
 .LOG_IN.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
      -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.CONTACT {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:540px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.CONTACT.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
      -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.ABOUT {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:450px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.ABOUT.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
      -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.XENOVA_ {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:330px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.XENOVA_.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
      -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.VERTICALS {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:210px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.VERTICALS.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
      -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.CREATORS {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:90px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.CREATORS.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
      -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.HOME {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.HOME.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 74;
  height: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
      -webkit-transition: font-size .5s;
}
.Logo.small:hover {
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 73;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
          -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.6s;
    transition: height 0.6s;
          -webkit-transition: width 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.6s;
    transition: width 0.6s;
}
.Logo:hover {
  background: url("images/LogoHover.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  width: 81px;
  height: 85px;
  z-index: 70;
  -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
}
.Logo {
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 81px;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 73;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.Logo.small {
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 73;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s;
}
.middle-nav {
  width: 750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/*SUB-MENUS */

.sub-menu-style {
  width:200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
}
.sub-menu-style.small {
  width:160px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.sub-menu-style.small:hover {
  width:170px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
  .sub-menu-style:hover {
  width:200px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  }
  .creator-sub {
  margin-left: 706px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  }

  .sub-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
   }

/*Initialize*/
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
}
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a.small{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  color: rgb( 51, 51, 51 );
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.91, 0.9);
}
.cnav {
    margin-left:40px !important; }
.vnav {
    margin-left:155px !important; }
.Xnav {
    margin-left:270px !important; }
.anav {
    margin-left:385px !important; }


}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
        -webkit-transition: display .5s;
  margin-top: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu.small{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
        -webkit-transition: display .5s;
      margin-left: 30px; 
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition: display .5s;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what's causing your problem, but I like your site

Comment: Can you put your code of your head (html and css)?

Comment: Yeah, give me a bit to single it out Jabel

Answer (score 2):

Its your use of `margin-left` to position elements like `.VERTICALS` or `.CREATORS`. These elements are absolutely positioned, but you have not set their `left` property. So when other elements trigger a reflow its repositioning based on `margin-left`.

You can fix this by using the `left` property instead of `margin-left`.

A good rule of thumb, is that if you are going to have absolutely positioned elements, then you should declare at least 2 of the following properties : `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, although if I use left, won't the elements move depending on screen resolution?

Comment: not really. Its a `px` vs `em` thing, not a `margin-left` vs `left` thing.

Comment: I understand that is going on, but I can't find a proper solution; using left will keep that element that amount left of the browser window, which means it will move depending on the screen site or zoom. If i'm not getting it, can you edit it to show me?

Comment: it's not based on the browser window, its based on the offset parent. I you wrap your page in a div with position relative you will be in good shape.

Comment: As you can see, the middle navigation is already wrapped in the class "middle-nav", which is not positioned absolutely, is 750px wide, and centered. Weird thing is "middle-nav" is only 17px high according the Chrome inspector, what's going wrong?

Comment: Looks like yo solved it since. How did you go about it? Also please accept my answer if you found it helpful.